# Mac OS X Lion - way to associate to only one BSSID and disable hopping? (WDS network)

Tags: mac, wireless-networking, osx-lion, wds

Question:
Is there any way on the Mac OS X Lion to force client connection to a specified BSSID?

Problem details:

I have been connection to WDS-based network and I can see three of the network's access points, all within similar signal range (same SSID, no encryption, open network).

The connection works well for a few minutes, then I can see a dropping of packets for a minute and my internet connection grinds to a halt. This usually resolves itself and starts working again.

I have been monitoring which AP I am actually associated to and instead of staying with the "best" AP, it somehow thinks that the other is better and tries to connect to it. Not to mention that it fails and returns back to the previous AP, which causes the unpleasant connection interruption.

Comment: Locking to a BSSID would be an interesting workaround, but it would be a pity not to fix the underlying problem with the network.

It would be interesting to see the output of `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport -s` to see what the signal strengths and radio types of those APs really is. It would also be interesting to see the output log from `/usr/libexec/airportd debug +AllUserland +AllDriver +AllVendor +LogFile` (log goes to `/var/log/wifi.log`) to see the reason why your client is roaming.

Comment: Thank you very much for you suggestion - I may actually like to play around figuring out what is going on, however, for the short term solution, is there a way to lock to a specific BSSID?

Comment: MacOS does not have a way to lock your laptop to a certain BSSID.  However, if your Access Point point allows for it, you could create an ACL (Access Control List) to block your MAC address from the two AP's you don't want to associate to.  Let me know if that works.